# Find files containing specific words - SublimeText2

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext

Is there a way in SublimeText2 to find files that contain all of the words I specify.  For example, I can search an entire folder for the word 'foo' but I am specifically looking for files that contain the words 'foo' and 'bar' (anywhere in the file, not necessarily together in the file).

I'm trying to use regex but that isn't working for me. I can use `foo|bar` but that will find either not both.  I'm not sure how to express 'AND' in regex.

Any help?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((foo)+.*)bar|bar(.*(foo)+)`

it's slow but works :) (not even really that slow! will come in handy in future for sure hehe thanks for inspiration to figure it out ;) )

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm going to take a look to see if a plugin is available that could enable this. :)

Comment: gimme a sec - i might have found a way to do that :) will update

Comment: Great work!!  Really appreciate you taking the time out for this.  Many thanks!